# Where to find dbt macros when wishing to edit it

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to implement a "merge_exclude_columns" configuration in my dbt project as suggested here:

https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pull/3100#issuecomment-904502858

My question is kind of basic - I assume I need to add this macro to the exsiting merge.sql macro but now sure where I'm suppose to find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps, the global dbt macros are located in the [following path](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/tree/main/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros) in the dbt-core repository. If you are specifically looking for the `merge.sql` implementation, it can be [found here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/1071a4681df91633301fdf23e34de819b66fbeb7/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/models/incremental/merge.sql).

You can override global dbt macros by creating a macro in your local project using the same name, therefore allowing re-implementation of the global macro. If you are wanting to implement additional logic in `merge.sql` I would suggest overriding it, include all existing code plus add anything additional to achieve your `merge_exclude_columns` configuration.

An example where this is often done is the `generate_schema_name` [macro](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/8442fb66a591c4f5353f8baaaaf62f846c5f5171/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/get_custom_name/get_custom_schema.sql), which handles how schema name concatenation behaves between project level and model level schema settings. By creating a macro named `generate_schema_name` in my own project I can override the global macro and define how I want schema concatenation to work in my own project.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed. 
I was wondering - Can altering the merge macro in the way I've mentioned above affect the performance of the merge operation or am I just altering the way the command is parsed?